# Function Investigation proof verification

Tags: functions, solution-verification

https://pasteboard.co/WMejlmetcznl.png

This is the question

We have,

\begin{gather}
f( m+n) \ =\ f( m) \ +\ f( n) \ +\ mn( m\ +\ n) \notag\\
\end{gather}
And we have to prove,

\begin{gather*}
f( n) \ =\ \sum _{i\ =\ 0}^{d} c_{i} n^{i}\\
f( n) \ =\ c_{0} \ +\ c_{1} n\ +\ c_{2} n^{2} \ +\ ...\ +\ c_{d} n^{d}\\
f( m) \ =\ c_{0} \ +\ c_{1} m\ +\ c_{2} m^{2} \ +\ ...\ +\ c_{d} m^{d}
\end{gather*}

So we have from the assumptions,
\begin{gather*}
f( m\ +\ n) \ =\ c_{0} \ +\ c_{1}( m\ +\ n) \ +\ c_{2}( m\ +\ n)^{2} \ +\ ...\ +\ c_{d}( m\ +\ n)^{d}\\
=\ f( n) \ +\ f( m) \ +\ 2c_{2} mn\ +\ 3c_{3} mn( m\ +\ n) \ +\ ...\\
\end{gather*}
We conclude from the above expression that $d$ has a maximum value of 3 and from (1) we get the relations,

\begin{gather*}
2c_{2} \ =\ 0,\ 3c_{3\ } \ =\ 1\\
\Longrightarrow \ f( n) \ =\ c_{0} \ +\ c_{1} n\ +\ \frac{1}{3} n^{3} ;\ c_{0} ,\ c_{1} \ \in \ \mathbb{R}
\end{gather*}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is almost correct, $c_0$ must be $0$.

Similar to [Solve $f(m + n) = f(m) + f(n) + mn$ and $g(mn) = g(m)g(n)(m + n)$ for $f \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3342051/solve-fm-n-fm-fn-mn-and-gmn-gmgnm-n-for-f-colon)

Let $g(n)=6f(n)-2n^3$. Then
\begin{align}
g(m+n)&=6f(m+n)-2(m+n)^3\\
      &=6(f(m)+f(n)+mn(m+n))-2(m^3+3m^2n+3mn^2+n^3)\\
      &=(6f(m)-2m^3)+(6f(n)-2n^3)\\
      &=g(m)+g(n)
\end{align}

Equations of the form $g(m+n)=g(m)+g(n)$ only have solutions $g(n)=cn$, thus,
$$g(n)=cn=6f(n)-2n^3$$
Thus,
$$f(n)=\frac{cn+2n^3}{6}.$$

Comment: okay c0 is 0 I get that but how did you write c1 as c1/6 I mean since c1 can take all real values I guess we are free to express it as any way we like right?

Comment: Also, g(m+n) = g(m) + g(n) is only valid when g(n) = kn but here we had an extra mn(m+n) term so I didn't use the assumption.

Comment: Since $c$ is any constant $c/6$ can also be any constant so you can write your final answer as $c_1n+1/3 n^3$. I'm not sure what you mean by the second comment. We used the assumption of $f(n)$ when showing $g(m+n)=g(m)+g(n)$.